# How to plot coordinate using basemap and file.csv

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib-basemap

I am in trouble with how to plot the coordinate given in a file.csv using basemap. It has error when I run with latlon=True. My code below :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap 

df=pd.read_csv('E:\Classification\DATA.csv')
lat=df['Latitude']
lon=df['Longitude']

plt.figure(figsize=(12,7))
m = Basemap(projection='mill',
           llcrnrlat = 7,
           urcrnrlat = 25,
           llcrnrlon = 90,
           urcrnrlon = 120,
           resolution = 'l')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries()
m.drawstates()
m.fillcontinents(color='None',lake_color='#FFFFFF')
m.drawmapboundary(color='k', linewidth=1.0, fill_color=None, zorder=None, ax=None)

parallels = np.arange(0.,81,10.)
# labels = [left,right,top,bottom]
m.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[False,True,True,False])
meridians = np.arange(10.,351.,5.)
m.drawmeridians(meridians,labels=[True,False,False,True])

m.scatter(lon,lat,latlon=True,c='red', marker='o',linewidth=1, zorder=2)

plt.show()
```

I really appreciate if some of you can help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Need a few lines in `DATA.csv` for testing.

Comment: My lattitude: 16.22 13.95 13.9 22.15
My longitude: 107.28 108.65 109.12 105.83

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `lon.values, lat.values` in place of `lon, lat` in `m.scatter()`.

```
m.scatter(lon.values, lat.values, latlon=True,c='red', marker='o',linewidth=1, zorder=2)
```

[image: vn]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.